# How to get an item from asp:Repeater in Event handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Repeater that is binded with some DataTable. (Here I skiped header template).

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_users" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_users_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rpt_users_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="c0">
            <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckSelect" runat="server" /></td>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_edit" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>'
                        NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "edit") %>'></asp:HyperLink></strong>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_del" runat="server" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "key") %>'><img src="assets/img/delete.png" alt="<%#nodeDelete %>" title="<%#nodeDelete %>" class="ico-delpage icon-right" /></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "country") %></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "daysleft") %>' OnTextChanged="Unnamed_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
<asp:Repeater>
```

I associated OnTextChanged event with a handler:

```
protected void Unnamed_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    int newDays = 0;
    try
    {
        newDays = int.Parse(txt);
    }
    catch { return; }

}
```

So, how to get the whole object that is associated with current row in Repeater? I need to get access to this object in my OnTextChanged event handler, because I need to get some data from this object that represents current row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the bound object of the repeater item in the OnTextChanged event. One way of doing this is as follows.

1. After retrieving the datatable, save the datatable in viewstate

   ViewState["Data"] = data;
2. Bind the key value of the individual item to a hidden field by adding a hidden field to the repeater item

   < asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenFieldKey" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval  (Container.DataItem, "key") %>' />
3. You can get the, repeater item and then the hidden field, to get the key of the row. Then the other values can be retrieved by finding the rows in the table which is stored in the viewstate.

   protected void Unnamed_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   ```
   var txt = (sender as TextBox).Text;
   var repeaterItem = (sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
   var hiddenFieldKey =repeaterItem.FindControl("hiddenFieldKey") as HiddenField;

   // Get data from viewstate
   DataTable data = ViewState["Data"] as DataTable;
   var dataRow= data.Rows.Find(hiddenFieldKey.Value);
   //You can use this row to get the values of the other columns

   int newDays = 0;
   try
   {
       newDays = int.Parse(txt);
   }
   catch { return; }
   ```

   }

Another way of doing is that, if you dont have many values to get, then bind all the required values in multiple hidden fields in the repeater item and then get those hidden field values in the OnTextChanged event

Comment: Changed step 2, added a space in the tag, somehow it is not accepting the correct format

Comment: I get Exception here `var dataRow = data.Rows.Find(hiddenFieldKey.Value);` MissingPrimaryKeyException. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sender` parameter, like you do for `Text`, `var tb = (TextBox)sender;`, then access that control's `Parent` property. You might have to go a couple levels up to find exactly what you're looking for, but that's the gist. Then you can use `FindControl` or whatever you need past that.